# Setter is invoked before constructor

Tags: oop, typescript

I am trying to create instances of class `HelloWorld`, however it does not work. I found that problem is that setter methods called instead of constructor which should initialize variable `name`, while variable `welcome` is optional.

I specified getters and setters for both variables. Browser's console is throwing an error about *maximum call stack size*. If I comment my getters&setters it stops throwing errors.

Could anyone explain me that strange behaviour?
Also there is another problem with *mapping*. I'm trying to "return" an array if `li` elements like in `React` by using `.map()`. It gives me the result with commas. How can I get rid of them while printing?

This is a link to my code https://codepen.io/CrUsH20/pen/yzMjzL?editors=1010

### Updated #1

I fixed the problem with getters&setters by giving a `_` sign for private values.

Now I have a problem with

```
function print() {
    if (invitations) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = invitations.map((e)=> {
            return `<li>${e.welcome + e.name}</li>`;
        });
    }
}
```

Compiler complains that `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.` in `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML` while type was not assigned since it is a html element

### Update #2

There are solutions:
1# About conflict with constructor and set&get - I changed object's values by adding to their names `_`. It solved the conflicts.
2# About commas - I added after `map` `.join('')` which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code (subset of yours) is a compile error:

```
class HelloWorld {
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }
    set name(e: string) {
        this.name = e;
    }
    get name(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

[image]

Garbage in => Garbage out

## Fix

Dont use getter / setters and properties with the same name.

Comment: But if I need to workout the same value? Firstly I should init the variable and then I need to have the ability to change it's property in future possible reasons

Comment: Also by some reason PhpStorm doesn't say anything about these variables.

Comment: Setters and getters are usually supposed to set and return a private field of a class.

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko I understand, but what about duplicating?

Comment: I've just seen your updates, nice to know it all works now!

Comment: Maybe this fork of your pen will give you some food for thoughts https://codepen.io/rasdaniil/pen/JrJQre

Comment: But.. the simplier the better :-) https://codepen.io/rasdaniil/pen/eGRwLK

Comment: The link before the last was supposed to be your class refactored... but I forgot to fork that pen and lost changes :-)
Something like this https://codepen.io/rasdaniil/pen/YrQoJz?editors=1010#anon-login

Good luck!